# Show the entire trust of chain using open_ssl

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl

I'm using the following command to show the entire chain of certificates:

```
openssl s_client \
  -servername myServer.com \
  -connect myServer.com:443 \
  -prexit \
  -showcerts
```

It works correctly but it does not show the certificate that belongs to the CA (the hash between **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----** and **-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----**). Jut the ones belonging to the leaf and the intermediate CA. Are you able to suggest me how to retrieve a pem?

The one I'm interested in is of Baltimore CyberTrust Root.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s_client -showcerts` shows all the certificates **the server sends**; this can omit the root cert and often does, depending on the server software and/or config. See [rfc5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2)

`certificate_list`

```
  This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
  certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
  certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
  certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
  independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
  certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
  assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
  validate it in any case.
```

slightly relaxed by [rfc8446](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4.2)

```
... The sender's certificate MUST come in the first
CertificateEntry in the list.  Each following certificate SHOULD
directly certify the one immediately preceding it.  Because
certificate validation requires that trust anchors be distributed
independently, a certificate that specifies a trust anchor MAY be
omitted from the chain, provided that supported peers are known to
possess any omitted certificates.
```

Thus generally an SSL-now-TLS client should already *have* a truststore containing the root certs (or possibly other anchors) to be used. OpenSSL code will *use* a 'CA file' and/or 'CA directory' if provided, including a system default one if you don't specify otherwise (which you didn't), but OpenSSL upstream does not provide such certs. Many builds or packages do, for example all Unix distros I have used provide a package `ca-certs` or similar, and configure openssl to use that (also configuring other software like Firefox/NSS and Java to use the same ca-certs). The curl project publishes [a port of the Mozilla/Firefox truststore](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) to PEM/OpenSSL format, which I use, and that does include "Baltimore CyberTrust Root". My Windows systems and Firefox(es) also have it, and can export a PEM. You normally select the root cert from the truststore using the Issuer name in the subordinate cert, here the intermediate CA cert, and/or AuthorityKeyIdentifier.

The X.509/PKIX format supports an extension field, caIssuer in AuthorityInformationAccess aka AIA, that gives a URL where the CA promises to provide a download of the parent certificate. Until recently AIA/caIssuer was very rarely provided but nowadays it has become more common (CABforum makes it a 'should'); I don't know particularly about CyberTrust (which is no longer Baltimore and now actually Digicert).

Select the last cert sent, which you say is the second, either by cut&paste or something like `openssl s_client -showcerts ... | awk '/-----BEGIN CERT/{x++} x==2' >file` then `openssl x509 -text -noout <file` and look for the AuthorityInformationAccess extension.

Note this isn't really secure; if your connection has been intercepted the adversary can send you a fake cert with fake caIssuer, which when you use it gets a fake root. To prevent that you need to verify the intermediate-CA cert using the root key, but to do that you must already have the root and so there's no reason to fetch it.

If you don't already have the root in a truststore and the intermediate doesn't give you caIssuer, you need to search, but that's easier since "Certificate Transparency" has become popular; now instead of having Google (or DDG etc) give you several websites you have to look at and use human thinking, you only need to look at one or more of the curated public logs. I like https://crt.sh as a frontend (there are others) and it instantly finds https://crt.sh/?id=76 and provides a download link (look down the left column).